# Different attribute selection widget in a view

Tags: commerce

I have a product display that lists multiple products with various pack sizes.
I added a taxonomy field to a Product for the attribute
e.g.
T shirt 1 pack
T shirt 3 pack

I have set the product display to list the pack sizes as a radio list for selection. Easy enough, in Configure Taxonomy Field I just set the "Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms." and set the attribute selection widget to Radio buttons.

I would also like to show all the product displays in a view, also easy however, I would like the add to cart form in the view to display the pack sizes as a Select list.

T Shirt > dropdown 1 & 3 pack
Trousers > dropdown 1 & 3 pack

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the field definition isn't context sensitive (i.e. it can't have one value on a standalone page and another on a View for that setting), you're going to have to do this yourself via a form alter. Just be mindful that the options array for radio buttons / select lists are treated differently with respect to sanitization when formatted for display.